# Invoking synchronous function in asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have problem understanding how async function work in JavaScript. Let's take the code below:

```
async () => {
      console.log(1);
      setTimeout(() => console.log(2)
        , 2000)
      console.log(3);
}
```

I would expect that invocation of synchronous function inside async should block thread before executing further code. So I'd expect to get `1 -> 2 -> 3` instead I'm getting `1 -> 3 -> 2`. Can't find explanation why it's happening and how to block thread to receive  output `1 -> 2 -> 3`.
I'm using Node 12 with serverless framework.

Comment: The sole purpose of `setTimeout` is to do something later in time, hence asynchronous.

Comment: The instructions you've given are literally "Print `1`; Print `2` after 2 seconds; Print `3`" That's *exactly* what you get - `1` -> `3`-> 2 second wait -> `2`. And async functions also are...async. Halting the thread because you've called a synchronous function in an async one also makes no sense. You are better off reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep) then asking about a concrete problem.

Comment: Ok that's my bad. I thought setTimeout is synchronous. My actual issue is with processing stream with https://github.com/request/request inside async AWS lambda function. Somehow when I invoke it locally everything works fine but in cloud it's not waiting for stream to be closed. But that is another topic. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` itself won't wait until execution of `setTimeout` finished as you expect. As you can read from the documentation - find here for [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> An async function can contain an await expression that pauses the execution of the async function to wait for the passed Promise's resolution, then resumes the `async` function's execution and evaluates as the resolved value.

Just built a quick example to see the difference between `async` and `await` solution and just using `setTimeout` as it is in your example.

Consider the following example:

```js
const getPromise = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
  });
}

const run = async () => {
  console.log('run started');
  setTimeout(() => console.log('setTimeout finised'), 2000);
  console.log('setTimeout started');
  const promise = await getPromise();
  console.log('Promise resolved');
  console.log('run finished');
}

run();
```

Steps explained:

1. Logging that function `run` execution started
2. Attaching an event to `setTimeout` which will be finished in ~2 seconds
3. Log into console that `setTimeout` started
4. Creating promise with `getPromise` function and with `await` keyword wait till `resolve`
5. In ~2 seconds `setTimeout` logs that it has been finished
6. In ~3 seconds from `Promise` the `resolve` function called
7. `run` function finishes its execution after `resolve` and logging.

I hope that helps you understand this portion of the code.

Answer (score 1):

> I would expect that invocation of synchronous function inside async should block thread before executing further code.

It does

> So I'd expect to get 1 -> 2 -> 3 instead I'm getting 1 -> 3 -> 2.

`setTimeout` is **not** synchronous. It very explicitly is for queuing up a function to run later, after some time has passed.

> Can't find explanation why it's happening and how to block thread to receive output 1 -> 2 -> 3.

You can't per se.

The closest you could come would be to replace `setTimeout` with a loop that runs around in circles until some time has passed… but that would be awful (it would lock up the UI for starters).

If you want to just run the three logs in order, then replace `setTimeout` with something that returns a promise and then `await` it (which would put the async function to sleep and let any other code continue to run until the promise resolved).

```js
const timeout = function() {
  return new Promise(function(res) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(2);
      res();
    }, 2000)
  })
};


const x = async() => {
  console.log(1);
  await timeout();
  console.log(3);
}

x();
```